# Custom UITableView with sections in one column and cells in next column

Tags: ios, uitableview

What is best way to create the below custom UITableView? How to proceed?
[image]

Comment: Have you looked at `UICollectionView`?

Comment: No I didn't worked with UIcollectionView before. Is that the best way to proceed?

Comment: `UICollectionView` would allow you to customise the layout if you subclass `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`.